# Do we ever learn Buddy's real name?

Tags: the-incredibles

Incredi-boy! Self-proclaimed as Mr. Incredible's biggest fan and super-in-training.

> Mr. Incredible: You're that kid from the fan club, Brody(?)... Buddy!
>
> Incredi-Boy: My name is Incredi-boy.

> Syndrome: ... after all, I am your biggest fan.
>
> Mr. Incredible: Buddy...
>
> Syndrome: MY NAME IS NOT BUDDY! And it's not Incredi-boy either, that ship has sailed.

---

Mr. Incredible keeps on calling this kid Buddy, but every time get told that is his name is NOT Buddy.

**Do we ever learn Buddy/Incredi-boy/Syndrome's "real" name?**

Comment: I think the point is that "Buddy" is his legal name, but not the name he chooses to identify himself with.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's "Guy", friend.

Comment: Don't know if it's a coincidence or a deliberate nod, but Brodie was the name of Jason Lee's character in Mallrats.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The film's end-credits (see below) indicate that Buddy Pine **is** his given name. It's certainly possible that since Buddy was intended by the animators to be something of a caricature of Pixar Producer [Brad Bird](http://pixar.wikia.com/wiki/Brad_Bird), that his name is actually short for *Bradley* (of which Buddy is a common contraction), but there's no specific indication in the movie that this is the case.

In the scene you're referring to, Syndrome is saying that his name is *now* ***Syndrome*** (e.g. his *self-chosen* super-villian name) rather than Buddy or Incredi-Boy.

[image]

Interestingly, in the [original screenplay](http://screenplayexplorer.com/wp-content/scripts/The-Incredibles.pdf), after Buddy tells Bob his new name, his character name changes.

> **BUDDY**: *Look at THAT! Am I good enough now?*
>
> (slams Bob into ground) *WHO'S SUPER NOW???*
>
> (slams Bob again) *I'm SYNDROME! Your nemesis! And—*
>
> **Syndrome** realizes he's lost Bob, inadvertently flinging him over the trees.
>
> **SYNDROME:** *Brilliant.*

Comment: Also in the introduction scene for buddy (set in the past) he does NOT say "no that is not my name" but only that he is his number one fan

Comment: Oh! Oh! Oh! Hand-drawn circle!

Comment: @DevSolar - Always good for a couple of extra upvotes

Answer (score 43):

Apparently, his name really is Buddy. IMDB lists the character's name as **Buddy Pine**/Syndrome. The character's voice is provided by Jason Lee, who some of you may remember from *My Name is Earl*.

Comment: So... His Name is Earl? ;)

Comment: @IMSoP No, his name is Buddy. Jason Lee's name is Earl :')

Comment: His name is Robert Paulson.

Comment: I personally remember him from Dogma ;)

Answer (score 3):

His birth name is Buddy, but the villian known as Syndrome has essentially done away with that name as he associates that with his weaker non-super self.

This is supported by the fact that after the line you mention, he monologues about the changes he's gone through since he was the young wanna be side-kick that was rejected by Mr. Incredible. He mentions that people only respect you when you're a threat and he built weapons and became wealthy in order to do that. Right after that monologue he states his name as Syndrome, which in his mind is the embodiment of how he is different and changed from his weaker original self, Buddy, and should be "respected".